# AJAX not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

When clicking the login button the AJAX call is not being fired. I can't see where I am going wrong.

```html
<script src="assets/dist/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnLogin").click(function() {
      var username = $("#inputEmail").val().trim();
      var password = $("#inputPassword").val().trim();
      
      if (username != "" && password != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'ajax/login.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {
            username: username,
            password: password
          },
          success: function(response) {
            var msg = "";
            if (response == 1) {
              window.location = "index.php";
            } else {
              msg = "Invalid username and password!";
            }
            $("#message").html(msg);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: We need to see the HTML in order to be able to help you. That said, my guess would be that `#btnLogin` is a `type="submit"` and it's inside a `form`. Therefore you're actually submitting that form and causing the current page to be unloaded before any AJAX call can complete.

Comment: <form class="form-signin">
  <div class="text-center mb-4">
    <div id="message"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
  </div>
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" id="btnLogin">Sign in</button>  
</form>

Comment: Please use the `edit` link under your question to update the code within it